# Vampire bite HP drain not healing after long rest

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, undead, hit-points, storm-kings-thunder

I'm playing in my first campaign as a Way of the Long Death Monk, currently level 6, and we're running Storm King's Thunder. I've been loving it, and everyone's been great including the DM, but I've been getting stressed about a situation.

Storm King's Thunder spoilers:

> We had an encounter with the vampire at the Bargewright Inn

I got bit and had my max HP reduced by 15 from 51 to 36. This was the first I had seen anything about this kind of effect. Normally I avoid looking up anything about enemies, but I just wanted to know I wouldn't be permanently affected, so I looked up vampires and it's supposed to heal after a long rest.

We've had 2 sessions and several long rests since and I'm still not back to max HP. If there's something important about this I don't want to undermine future plans or suggest I have any issue with consequences by going to the DM and expressing concern, but I feel kind of crippled losing 30% of my max HP when I was building my character around survivability. I also can't find anything about a wound having this long of an effect outside of actually turning undead. Nobody else was bit so it's just me hampered in some way.

If this is something in Storm King's Thunder and this particular vampire, I'd rather know what it is and how long it would last up front. If not I'm not sure what I should do.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and get a nifty badge. This will help you to help us to maintain the quality of questions and answers around this SE.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Ask your DM

Even though the base [Vampire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vampire)'s max HP reduction from Bite goes away after a long rest the DM could have made a change to have the creature leave a lasting impression.

**Don't be scared to talk to your DM. Just like anyone else, a DM can forget something or misread.**

I recommend talking to the DM. Don't specifically say you looked it up but just ask if your character will eventually get over it or if it will take a *remove curse* spell, *lesser restoration*, etc. Lycanthropy takes a *remove curse*; same thing for mummy rot.

Answer (score 1):

You could always start your character on a path of healing. Seeking out healing until you have meet your goal. Kind of like a side quest. Just stop proceeding in the main quest-line until you are satisfied with the your character's goal of being healed.

Obviously, work with your GM. It could be a fun side quest if the drain was meant to last longer than a long rest.